# Changing three standalone mongodb servers with exactly the same data into a replica set

Tags: mongodb

I have three standalone MongoDB database servers with exactly the same data   (Created from the same snapshot) How can I convert that to a replica set? (Ideally without the need to wipe, and re-sync from a selected master node)

Comment: Could you create a 1 member replicaset with one of the nodes and then copy the local database over to the other nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this isn't possible. You know that the data is exactly the same on all members, MongoDB doesn't.

In that case MongoDB would have to go over all the data and make sure it's identical, which is time consuming in the order of magnitude of copying all the data.